# IntelliJ IDEA 13 extremely slow compilation

Tags: java, performance, intellij-idea, compilation

After setting up IntelliJ IDEA 13 with java 8 sdk for the first time i've noticed that the compilation process was extremely slow. Printing out a simple 'Hello world!' took exactly 3 minutes and 38 seconds. I have no idea what is causing it to be so slow. When i run the code in Netbeans for example it compiles and runs instantly. I've done some research and sought for solutions but other than removing plugins i wasn't able to find anything. Does anyone here have any idea what might cause this problem?

Comment: Please create an issue with a cpu snapshot, so they can fix it.

Comment: I think I have the same problem. Hello World using the console application template with JDK8 compiles in 12 seconds on my machine (Core i7, SSD, 8GB RAM)

Comment: How to go back to IDEA 11 guys ??

Comment: Having this same problem.It sucks.I really like the UI for intellj but unfortunately, it's one problem or the other.

Comment: I had the same problem on my mac. Then I found out this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39698914/11826812) This solved my problem. It says it is because of the jvm takes a long time to resolve ip-address for localhost. Then It shows you how to on mac. Before it was building a project in 35 seconds, now it takes 5 seconds for the same action.

Answer (score 4):

Try to increase Build Process heap size. 
[image: Here is pictorial detail how to increase Build heap size]

Comment: It works for IDEA version 2022. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to disable every unwanted plugins that you have.

Go to Preferences > Plugins > Installed and then you can check all your installed plugins that you have. You can deselect Kotlin if you are not thinking to use it (or code with that language) and other stuff that you will not use.
Apply it and test it. 
See
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-IVAGtnRkzg

It worked for me.

Comment: Maybe you can add a sentence about the content and not only link the video. Explain how to disable the plugins.

Comment: I thought that it will be easier to just link the video so that people can see how to disable plugins. Anyway, go to Preferences--->Plugins--->Installed and then you can check all your installed plugins that you have. ex you can deselect Kotlin if you are not thinking to use it (or code with that language) and other stuff that you will not use it.

Comment: Another link that might be helpful if you have a MAC.:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289695/inetaddress-getlocalhost-slow-to-run-30-seconds/33289897#33289897

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. Upgrade your machine, you will definitely need one with an 8GB RAM. Also, reinstall IntelliJ with only the components that you need, this will increase the startup time of IntelliJ. Make sure you do not have any memory intensive program running along with IntelliJ in your current system. These things helped me.