# Java Derby painfully slow after upgrade to MacOS Sierra

Tags: java, derby

I have an application which includes Derby which have been working fine, both on Windows and on Mac.

When I upgrade my Mac to Sierra it still was no problem but I had some users complaining that after upgrade to Sierra the application was very slow.

Yesterday I went out and when I came back I had the same problem (not sure but I might reboot my system before I went out).

I run profiler in NetBeans and suddenly everything was fine but when I run it as normal Derby calls is at least 10 times slower.

I have tried adding my computer to hosts [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636792/sbt-test-extremely-slow-on-macos-sierra) but it didn´t improve performance.

Comment: Did the upgrade also represent a change to the version of Java that is running on your machine? What are the precise versions of Java, and of Derby? Since you can reproduce the problem, here's a checklist that you can follow to start to narrow down the problem: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/PerformanceDiagnosisTips

Comment: Thanks for reply, I went back to an earlier version and remade my changes and it now works. It was easier than trying to track the error.