# Gradle builds are very slow after upgrading to Mac OS Sierra

Tags: java, macos, gradle

Im working with gradle (2.8) to build,test our Spring java(1.8) applications

I have installed OSX Sierra last week, but sometime this week, my gradle clean test took 7-10 min to run instead of 15sec!!!

the build was hanging at this line...

```
Building 55% > :sandbox-core:compileJava > Resolving dependencies ':sandbox-core:compile' > Resolving dependencies 'detachedConfiguration3' > Resolving dependencies 'detachedConfiguration4'
```

incrementing the Resolving dependencies 'detachedConfigurationXXX' by 1 every now and then!!

once those detachedConfiguration were done, the test were running fine ..

But it took 7-10 min.

This is making me crazy!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636792/sbt-test-extremely-slow-on-macos-sierra)

It does not look related!!! but My problem went away as soon as i added my computer-name.local to /etc/hosts file on my Mac!!

```
127.0.0.1   localhost yourmacname.local
::1         localhost yourmacname.local
```

Your Mac name should be indicated when you open a terminal window ;-)
or in System informations app (at the bottom)