# IntelliJ IDEA with PHP plugin: slow localhost server request

Tags: php, intellij-idea

I try to write some tests with cURL for my server PHP application, and I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with the PHP plugin for development (Windows 10). Unfortunately, even though the scripts are local, and I request pages such as `http://localhost:63342/test.php?test1=example`, the request is very slow, and is taking about half a second. When I run the script via the IDE in command line mode, it's instant, but opening the URL in the browser has the same issue. I tried using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, but it didn't help. Also, I tried searching for a solution, nothing helped.

Do you have any idea how to make the URL request instant, similarly to launching the script in command line? Thanks.

Comment: What OS do you use? Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/39698914/104891 help?

Comment: @CrazyCoder It's Windows 10. Unfortunately it doesn't