# IntelliJ IDEA debugger is too slow to start on macOS

Tags: java, macos, performance, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA debugger is too slow on my new MacBook Pro 13 inch TouchBar model (late 2016). It has an i5 2.9ghz (6th Gen) and 8 GB ram.

Is there something wrong with processing power or is something else wrong? On my pc (i5 4670k, 8gb) the same version runs fine.

Comment: Are you running 64-bit IntelliJ?

Comment: What do you mean by `slow`? Is it slow to start or slow to step? Did you check https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544799?

Comment: That processor is literally slower than your desktop processor

Comment: @CrazyCoder Asking a high rep user: shouldn't this question be flagged as on the wrong network? This is a hardware problem, not a coding problem.

Comment: @Nathan it's a common software problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39698914/104891 for example.

Comment: I checked it, it's not like it's slow..but it kinda freezes which is uncommon

Comment: @Nathan that off-topic rule specifically says for non-coding tools, since this is about IntelliJ and Java debuggin it's within topic

Comment: Once again, freezing when starting debugger for the first time or when stepping? Do you have method breakpoints? Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/a/39698914/104891? Maybe it's the case?

Comment: @RayS.Kan you need to be as specific as possible. When is it slow? when it starts, when you are stepping through code. What do you mean? We can't read your mind

Comment: When I start debugger for first time it takes a minute to start up debug session (freezes), after that ..each time I hit debug ..it takes a bit less time ...which is still uncommon

Comment: Also there are no method breakpoints ..only line breakpoints, for processing power part, is my macbook pro really that bad? I mean most coders use the same machine only ..they don't face same

Comment: So in the end this is a duplicate of [Jvm takes a long time to resolve ip-address for localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39698914/104891). Unfortunately I cannot change my close vote.

Comment: Problem is solved in deed, yes it turns out this is a duplicate of the problem where localhost name resolution takes quite a long time on macOS. This however is step by step guide answer with some external reference and sums up everything in simple words.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may have a problem with DNS, see the [following answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39698914/104891):

```
git clone https://github.com/thoeni/inetTester
java -jar ./bin/inetTester.jar
```

Find the hostname that's output from the .jar.

`sudo nano /etc/hosts` and add these two entries.

```
127.0.0.1 <output-host-name>.local
::1 <output-host-name>.local
```

Comment: I will try it but just a quick question...what has DNS to do with debugging a simple non web app

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA debugger uses `localhost` to connect to the target VM, on Mac `localhost` resolution can take a lot of time (30-60 seconds) in some cases.

Comment: This would basically mean that this question is a duplicate of the linked one…

Comment: @DidierL, yes, but it also provides the detailed step by step instructions for the solution vs a link to the external site.

Comment: Thanks , now debugger fires up in a second.

Comment: Even if the jar executes fast, you should still update your `etc/hosts` because it still does make a difference.

Answer (score 6):

Agree with CrazyCoder. There is an easier way for obtaining/modifying hostname instead of using the github repo.

1. In system preference, click sharing

[image]

2. Click edit in the popup window. In my case, the hostname is MacBook.local.

[image]

3. sudo vi /etc/hosts

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add one more case. If we have a number of `method breakpoints`, then the Intellij will run extremely slow.