# Running two projects on IntelliJ suffers from slow performance

Tags: performance, intellij-idea, project, switching

Currently, I'm making web-apps using php [backend] project and AngularJS [frontend] project. To make above two projects simultaneously, I need to run 2 programs (Webstorm and IntelliJ).

But, I want to run two projects just using IntelliJ. I already tried before, but the IntelliJ performance was so bad and I don't know why. (I gave IntelliJ 4G of RAM and other options to run it smoothly, but it also returns slow performance.)

I installed Angularjs support, PHP/Laravel support, and Java/Spring support, and other plugins on IntelliJ.

I assume that this made IntelliJ slow, but I need to use above plugins to keep developing.

I'm using webstorm and Intellij for both front and back-end programming in fast speed.

In this case, do you have any idea to improve performance of IntelliJ when Running 2 programs simultaneously on intelliJ?

The reasons why I'm trying to run just IntelliJ are I just have only IntelliJ license and switching between front-end and back-end program is easier than 2 program. (It can be done just by command + ` to switch both project, but I need to command tab many times to switch between project. It makes me hesitate.)

If you have idea or have any manual which I didn't find before, please let me know.

Comment: Please report new issue on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA  attaching logs folder zipped (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) and CPU dump: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Comment: Hi @y.bedrov! Thank you for your comment. I think there are no options in my case after saw your reply. is it right? If then, i will report this on youtrack. Thank you again, and have a good day!

Comment: It's hard to guess what might cause slowness without additional logs. All I could suggest is to try to increase Xmx for IDEA: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?  I am experiencing the same problem.  Did you ever submit an issue in YouTrack?

Comment: @randymay Hi randymay, i unfortunately re-installed my overall system. I think my IntelliJ Configuration had problem.Sorry for not giving you good answer. Hope you solve this problem

Comment: I had the same problem on my mac. Then I found out this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39698914/11826812) This solved my problem. It says it is because of the jvm takes a long time to resolve ip-address for localhost. Then It shows you how to on mac. Before it was building a project in 35 seconds, now it takes 5 seconds for the same action.