# java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost take 100% CPU time

Tags: java, windows-10

The question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636792/jvm-takes-a-long-time-to-resolve-ip-address-for-localhost) but:

1. I have windows 10 OS
2. a java process is running for 3+ days when problem appeared

Any suggestion about fix?

java version:

```
java 9.0.1
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```