# Apache Zeppelin: each page takes minutes to load

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have a fresh Zeppelin download.

First I ran it via docker, everything is good. Then I stopped the Docker containers to clean it up. I did not save any notebooks.

Next I ran Zeppelin locally via

```
zeppelin-daemon.sh start
```

And I immediately noticed that the UI was extremely slow to load. Upon checking the network tab I find each resource taking 30-60 seconds to load, resulting in entire page taking 3-5 minutes.

How do I fix this, or even start to figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These tickets and another SO thread solved my problem.

Without digging deeper, it appears some JVM-based web server is taking an unreasonable amount of time finding localhost. The quick hack is just to add loca hostname to hosts file, i.e.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost <mbpro.local>
::1         localhost <mbpro.local>
```

use the hostname command to find out what's the right hostname, and replace <mbpro.local>.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2948

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-5023

[Jvm takes a long time to resolve ip-address for localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636792/jvm-takes-a-long-time-to-resolve-ip-address-for-localhost/39698914#39698914)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29281551)

Comment: @slideshowp2 I wonder what kind of people would vote delete instead of edit. Even if it were to stay in the current form, people who stumble upon the same problem can save quite a bit of time just by looking at the link titles. This kind of zeal does no good.